# HTML / CSS Delay

Tags: css

Can someone tell me how to add a pause for a few seconds once the text has been written and then for it to loop and do the same again?

I've added the code below:

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end) infinite,
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

Kind regards,

J

Comment: that delay can be set inside the keyframes itself, add a step of the same value that represents that delay you look for (increase the animation time too) `@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
 80%,  to { width: 100% }
}`

Comment: I already gave you answer to your old question. Better consider *all* the answer you get before asking a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extend the "@keyframes typing" ending time.
Before your tying ends where the width gets to 30% and it will restart right away, but having the end time extended. The animation will be "delayed".

See the snippet below

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}


/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(30, end) infinite, blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>
    writing text
  </h1>
</div>
```